# Pointers to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've read those articles http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c/
 http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/04/06/pointers-vs-arrays-in-c-part-2d/

I want some further explanation about what happens.

```
int joe[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

void test(int (*p)[4])
```

This is a pointer to an array which is different from

```
void test(int *d);
```

which is going to be a pointer to the first element of the array passed, or a copy of another pointer.
Can I do?

```
*p = joe //I guess not, I'm obtaining the array passed, and I'm trying to reassign it (which can't be done)
d = joe //I guess not, but I would like to know what would happen to d
*d = joe //Same as above
d = &joe //I'm giving to d the address of joe, what will it be?
```

Which of those are correct and which of those are wrong, and why.

In the article about 2d arrays (which actually are just 1d array), he wrote that:

```
void bar(int arr[2][3], int m, int n)
void bar(int arr[][3], int m, int n)
void bar(int (*arr)[3], int m, int n)
```

are all correct.

1) Question:

```
void bar(int arr[][3], int m, int n)
void bar(int arr*[3], int m, int n)
```

Are the same? If not what is the difference between them?

2) question:

```
 void bar(int arr[][3], int m, int n)
 void bar(int (*arr)[3], int m, int n)
```

What is the difference between those, and why do they both works?

I would really appreciate a detailed explanation of what happens behind, I hope the questions are clears.

Comment: You can enter it into a .c file and compile it. The compiler will tell, whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Immediately after second code block: "which is going to be a pointer to the first element of the array passed..." this is not accurate. `d` is a pointer *variable* (in this case a parameter variable as well). it *holds* an address. Whether that address references the foot of an array, a single `int`, or even NULL, you can NOT conclusively say it is a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: @WhozCraig if I pass to it this: int i[2] = {0,1}, it is going to be a pointer to the first element of i.

Comment: Yes, if you pass it. Just looking at the prototype without *knowing* what is passed from the caller side, you cannot deduce anything beyond that you have been given an address. This was effectively my point. You, the caller, can *know* it is an array, but the code in the function (the callee) has nothing to enforce that it is, in fact, an array.

Comment: int (*p)[4] is an array of pointers not pointer to an array

Comment: @BhavikShah No, `int *p[4]` would be an array of pointers, `int (*p)[4]` is a pointer to an array (of four `int`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function parameter declaration

```
void bar(int arr[]); /* this is a pointer to int */
```

is equivalent to

```
void bar(int arr[5]); /* this is a pointer to int, compiler just ignores 5 */
```

is equivalent to

```
void bar(int *arr); /* this is a pointer to int */
```

In all cases a *pointer* to an int or *pointer* to an array of ints is given to `bar()`. Note especially *pointer*. This means inside `bar()`, `sizeof(arr)` will always be `sizeof(int*)`, never `sizeof(int[5])` or `sizeof(int[3])` for example.

The rest, including multi dimensional arrays, follows from this simple rule.

Question 1)

- The compiler would tell you, that `void bar(int arr*[3], ...)` is invalid.
- Moving `*` to the front would give `void bar(int *arr[3], ...)`, which is an array of `int*` and translates to a pointer to a pointer: `int **arr`.
- This is different from `void bar(int arr[][3], ...)`, which is  a pointer to an array of 3 ints or pointer to a multi dimensional array with the second dimension being 3.

Question 2)

- There's no difference between these two. Both are pointer to an array of 3 ints as in question 1 above.

Further reading from [google: interpret c declaration](http://www.google.de/search?q=interpret+c+declaration)

- http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

And one last advice: don't be shy and use the compiler. It will tell you whether your code is valid or not.

Comment: An important note about this: You loose the size information for the array, either way you pass it. So it's not possible to do `sizeof(array)` to get the size of the array.

Comment: Also important, the leading subscript magnitude on a naked array parameter is effectively ignored. `ar[4][5]` is the same as `ar[][5]` as far as the compiler is concerned. Just as `ar[n]` is effectively `ar[]`.

Comment: void bar (int (*arr)[4]), this is a pointer to an array, what is the difference between this one and yours?

Comment: @AR89 There's no difference between parameters `int (*arr)[4]` and `int arr[][4]`.

Comment: One last question, both of them points to the first element of the array? As if it would with parameter `int *arr`, then given this: `int arr[2][3]` passed to it I would scan it with `arr[i*3+j]`

Comment: @AR89 When you have a multi dimensional array, declare it as such. Use `int arr[][3]` or `int (*arr)[3]`, but *not* `int *arr`. You can of course interpret it as `arr[i*3+j]`, but I don't recommend it. Better use `arr[i][j]`!